# block  delegate methods of class in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am having a problem I am working on a class which is subclass of UITextField.
Which will be used in many classes further.
But I don't want to let user to use it's delegate methods in any way.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: The programmer uses the delegate! The user has no clue, use or control of it whatsoever. I think you meant to convey something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `setDelegate:` so that it throws an exception or logs an instruction on what to do. That way your API users will know what's actually going on.

```
-(void) setDelegate: (id <UITextFieldDelegate>) delegate
{
    NSLog(@"*** Use the blocks API instead of calling %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector: _cmd];
}
```

Comment: [self doesNotRecognizeSelector: _cmd];
this crashes the application ..do you mean that do not allow user to call this method at all ?

Comment: +1 Yes It really works but can you please answer my question (in comments)

Comment: All `doesNotRecognizeSelector:` does is throw an exception. The point is to prevent API clients from calling `setDelegate:`. It's a radical means, so chances are you don't need it. I provided it as an example of what _can_ be done. If you think it's too annoying/destructive, you can just `NSLog()` a message and return without calling `super`.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `-setDelegate:` method such that it never actually sets a delegate. You can just provide an empty method that fails to call `super`:

```
-(void) setDelegate:(id<UITextFieldDelegate>) delegate
{
    // this method intentionally empty to prevent a delegate from ever being set
}
```